# React DND not working, REACT-JS Kanban app

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm currently working on to make a simple Kanban board that allows drag and drop task from one board to another. However, when task card is empty, the board doesn't accept the drag and drop. Furthermore, even when drag and drop works, the cursor is showing warning sign.

[Drag and Drop not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85qGW.png)

Here is my code block.

This is my trellocard.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AlignLeft, CheckSquare, MoreHorizontal } from "react-feather";

// import { formatDate } from "../../Helper/Util";

import "./styleTrelloCard.css";
import MainCard from "../../../../../component/cards/MainCard";
import Chip from "../../../../../component/extended/Chips";
import CardInfo from "./CardInfo";
import Menu from "./Menu";

function TrelloCard(props) {
  const { card, boardId, removeCard, onDragEnd, onDragEnter, updateCard } =
    props;
  const { id, title, desc, date, tasks, labels } = card;
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {showModal && (
        <CardInfo
          onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
          card={card}
          boardId={boardId}
          updateCard={updateCard}
        />
      )}
      <MainCard
        className="card"
        key={card.id}
        draggable
        onDragEnd={() => onDragEnd(boardId, id)}
        onDragEnter={() => onDragEnter(boardId, id)}
        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
      >
        <div className="card-top">
          <div className="card-top-labels">
            {labels?.map((item, index) => (
              <Chip key={index} item={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div
            className="card-top-more"
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              setShowDropdown(true);
            }}
          >
            <MoreHorizontal />
            {showDropdown && (
              <Menu
                class="board-dropdown"
                onClose={() => setShowDropdown(false)}
              >
                <p onClick={() => removeCard(boardId, id)}>Delete Card</p>
              </Menu>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card-title">{title}</div>
        <div>
          <p title={desc}>
            <AlignLeft />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="card-footer">
          {/* {date && (
            <p className="card-footer-item">
              <Clock className="card-footer-icon" />
              {formatDate(date)}
            </p>
          )} */}
          {tasks && tasks?.length > 0 && (
            <p className="card-footer-item">
              <CheckSquare className="card-footer-icon" />
              {tasks?.filter((item) => item.completed)?.length}/{tasks?.length}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </MainCard>
    </>
  );
}

export default TrelloCard;
```

this is my Board.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MoreHorizontal } from "react-feather";

import CustomInput from "../../../../../ApiMockData/CustomInput";

import MainCard from "../../../../../component/cards/MainCard";
import "./style.css";
import TrelloCard from './trelloCard';
import Menu from './Menu'

function Board(props) {
  const {
    board,
    addCard,
    removeBoard,
    removeCard,
    onDragEnd,
    onDragEnter,
    updateCard,
  } = props;
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MainCard className="board" key={board?.id} sx={{
      width: '280px'
    }}>
        <div className="board-header">
          <p className="board-header-title">
            {board?.title}
            <span>{board?.cards?.length || 0}</span>
          </p>
          <div
            className="board-header-title-more"
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              setShowDropdown(!showDropdown);
            }}
          >
            <MoreHorizontal />
            {showDropdown && (
              <Menu
                className="board-dropdown"
                onClose={() => setShowDropdown(false)}
              >
                <p onClick={() => removeBoard(board?.id)}>Delete Card</p>
              </Menu>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="board-cards custom-scroll">
          {board?.cards?.map((item) => (
            <TrelloCard
              key={item.id}
              card={item}
              boardId={board.id}
              removeCard={removeCard}
              onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
              onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
              updateCard={updateCard}
            />
          ))}
          <CustomInput
            text="+ Add Card"
            placeholder="Enter Card Title"
            displayClass="board-add-card"
            editClass="board-add-card-edit"
            onSubmit={(value) => addCard(board?.id, value)}
          />
        </div>
    </MainCard>
  );
}

export default Board;
```

and this is my content.jsx where i have my drag and drop code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ContentTitle from './title';
// import TaskWrapper from '../../../../component/tasks/TaskWrapper';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import Board from './board';
import { fetchBoardList, updateLocalStorageBoards } from '../../../../ApiMockData/Helper/APILayer';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 40px;
`;

const types = {
  all: 'All tasks',
  backlog: 'Backlog',
  progress: 'In Progress',
  complete: 'Complete',
};

const Content = () => {

  const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  async function fetchData() {
    const boardsData = await fetchBoardList();
    setBoards(boardsData);
    console.log(boardsData)
  }

  const [targetCard, setTargetCard] = useState({
    boardId: 0,
    cardId: 0,
  });

  const removeBoard = (boardId) => {
    const boardIndex = boards.findIndex((item) => item.id === boardId);
    if (boardIndex < 0) return;

    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    tempBoardsList.splice(boardIndex, 1);
    setBoards(tempBoardsList);
  };

  const addCardHandler = (boardId, title) => {
    const boardIndex = boards.findIndex((item) => item.id === boardId);
    if (boardIndex < 0) return;

    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    tempBoardsList[boardIndex].cards.push({
      id: Date.now() + Math.random() * 2,
      title,
      labels: [],
      date: '',
      tasks: [],
      desc: '',
    });
    setBoards(tempBoardsList);
  };

  const removeCard = (boardId, cardId) => {
    const boardIndex = boards.findIndex((item) => item.id === boardId);
    if (boardIndex < 0) return;

    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    const cards = tempBoardsList[boardIndex].cards;

    const cardIndex = cards.findIndex((item) => item.id === cardId);
    if (cardIndex < 0) return;

    cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
    setBoards(tempBoardsList);
  };

  const updateCard = (boardId, cardId, card) => {
    const boardIndex = boards.findIndex((item) => item.id === boardId);
    if (boardIndex < 0) return;

    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    const cards = tempBoardsList[boardIndex].cards;

    const cardIndex = cards.findIndex((item) => item.id === cardId);
    if (cardIndex < 0) return;

    tempBoardsList[boardIndex].cards[cardIndex] = card;

    setBoards(tempBoardsList);
  };

  const onDragEnd = (boardId, cardId) => {
    const sourceBoardIndex = boards.findIndex((item) => item.id === boardId);
    if (sourceBoardIndex < 0) return;

    const sourceCardIndex = boards[sourceBoardIndex]?.cards?.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === cardId
    );
    if (sourceCardIndex < 0) return;

    const targetBoardIndex = boards.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === targetCard.boardId
    );
    if (targetBoardIndex < 0) return;

    const targetCardIndex = boards[targetBoardIndex]?.cards?.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === targetCard.cardId
    );
    if (targetCardIndex < 0) return;

    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    const sourceCard = tempBoardsList[sourceBoardIndex].cards[sourceCardIndex];
    tempBoardsList[sourceBoardIndex].cards.splice(sourceCardIndex, 1);
    tempBoardsList[targetBoardIndex].cards.splice(
      targetCardIndex,
      0,
      sourceCard
    );
    setBoards(tempBoardsList);

    setTargetCard({
      boardId: 0,
      cardId: 0,
    });
  };

  const onDragEnter = (boardId, cardId) => {
    if (targetCard.cardId === cardId) return;
    setTargetCard({
      boardId: boardId,
      cardId: cardId,
    });
  };

  const addboardHandler = (name) => {
    const tempBoardsList = [...boards];
    tempBoardsList.push({
      id: Date.now() + Math.random() * 2,
      title: name,
      cards: [],
    });
    setBoards(tempBoardsList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateLocalStorageBoards(boards);
  }, [boards]);

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
      <ContentTitle addBoard={addboardHandler}
 />
      <Box sx={{
        marginTop: '35px',
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr))',
        gridTemplateRows: 'none',
        gridColumnGap: '20px',
        gridRowGap: '20px'
      }}>
        {boards.map((item) => (
            <Board
              key={item.id}
              board={item}
              addCard={addCardHandler}
              removeBoard={() => removeBoard(item.id)}
              removeCard={removeCard}
              onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
              onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
              updateCard={updateCard}
            />
          ))}

      </Box>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};




export default Content;
```

If anyone knows the answer, it'll be a big help. Thank you and have a nice day!